# Why does this Applescript cause "Export Library.scpt: execution error: System Events got an error: Can’t get process "i". (-1728)"?

Tags: applescript

ƒIt's caused when run through osascript from terminal using the command line "osascript Export\ Library.scpt /Users/bryandunphy/Development/iTunesLibraryConsolidator testing.xml".

same script as my last (solved) question but posting it's entirety this time.

```
-- `menu_click`, by Jacob Rus, September 2006
--
-- Accepts a list of form: `{"Finder", "View", "Arrange By", "Date"}`
-- Execute the specified menu item.  In this case, assuming the Finder
-- is the active application, arranging the frontmost folder by date.

on menuClick(mList)
local appName, topMenu, r

-- Validate our input
if mList's length < 3 then error "Menu list is not long enough"

-- Set these variables for clarity and brevity later on
set {appName, topMenu} to (items 1 through 2 of mList)
set r to (items 3 through (mList's length) of mList)

-- This overly-long line calls the menu_recurse function with
-- two arguments: r, and a reference to the top-level menu
tell application "System Events" to my menuClickRecurse(r, ((process appName)'s ¬
    (menu bar 1)'s (menu bar item topMenu)'s (menu topMenu)))
end menuClick

on menuClickRecurse(mList, parentObject)
    local f, r

-- `f` = first item, `r` = rest of items
set f to item 1 of mList
if mList's length > 1 then set r to (items 2 through (mList's length) of mList)

-- either actually click the menu item, or recurse again
tell application "System Events"
    if mList's length is 1 then
        click parentObject's menu item f
    else
        my menuClickRecurse(r, (parentObject's (menu item f)'s (menu f)))
    end if
end tell
end menuClickRecurse

-- Created by Bryan Dunphy during January of 2017
--
-- select the folder "directory" in Window "WinName" of Application "appName" and then clicks the default button if requested
-- if WinName is "" then it uses the frontmost window (to allow for unnamed windows)
-- REQUIRES "on handleDir" and "on findRoot" to work!
-- ONLY call switchDir
-- "createIt" is a boolean that will create any missing directories if it is set to "true".
-- "selectDefault" is a boolean indicating whether or not to click the window's default button after selecting the specified directory
-- returns "true" or "false" to indicate success.
-- clicks "Cancel" button on failure
-- Always returns "true" if "createIt" is set to "true"
on switchDir(directory, winName, appName, createIt, selectDefault)
    local dirs, delim
    set delim to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "/"
    set dirs to every text item of directory
    tell application "System Events" to tell process appName to set frontmost to true
    my findRoot(appName, winName)
    repeat with dir in dirs
        if not handleDir(dir, winName, createIt) then
            tell application "System Events" to tell process appName to tell button "Cancel" to click
            return false
        end if
    end repeat
    if selectDefault then keystroke return
    return true
end switchDir

on handleDir(dir, winName, appName, createIt)
    local foundIt
    foundIt = false
    local ndx
    if winName is not "" then
        repeat with ndx from 1 to (count of window winName's list 1)
            if window winName's list 1's item ndx's value is equal to dir then
                select window winName's list 1's item ndx
                foundIt = true
                exit repeat
            end if
        end repeat
    else
        repeat with ndx from 1 to (count of front window's list 1)
            if front window's list 1's item ndx's value is equal to dir then
                select front window's list 1's item ndx
                foundIt = true
                exit repeat
            end if
        end repeat
    end if
    if not foundIt then
        if createIt then
            if winName is not "" then
                tell application "System Events" to tell process appName to tell window winName
                    tell button "New Folder"
                        click
                        repeat until window "New Folder" exists
                            delay 0.5
                        end repeat
                        set value of text field 1 of window "New Folder" to dir
                        tell button "Create" to click
                        return my handleDir(dir)
                    end tell
                end tell
            else
                tell application "System Events" to tell process appName to tell its front window
                    tell button "New Folder"
                        click
                        repeat until window "New Folder" exists
                            delay 0.5
                        end repeat
                        set value of text field 1 of window "New Folder" to dir
                        tell button "Create" to click
                        return my handleDir(dir)
                    end tell
                end tell
            end if
        end if
    else
        return foundIt
    end if
end handleDir

on findRoot(appName, winName)
    local rootName
    if winName is not "" then
        tell application "System Events" to tell process appName to tell window winName
            tell pop up button 1
                click
                repeat until menu 1 exists
                    delay 0.5
                end repeat
                local ndx
                repeat with ndx from 1 to (count of menu 1)
                    if the title of menu 1's menu item ndx is "" then
                        set rootName to the title of menu 1's menu item (ndx - 1)
                        select (menu 1's menu item (ndx - 1))
                        exit repeat
                    end if
                end repeat
            end tell
        end tell
    else
        tell application "System Events" to tell process appName's front window
            tell pop up button 1
                click
                repeat until menu 1 exists
                    delay 0.5
                end repeat
                local ndx
                repeat with ndx from 1 to (count of menu 1)
                    if the title of menu 1's menu item ndx is "" then
                        set rootName to the title of menu 1's menu item (ndx - 1)
                        select (menu 1's menu item (ndx - 1))
                        exit repeat
                    end if
                end repeat
            end tell
        end tell
    end if
    return rootName
end findRoot

on run (clp)
    if clp's length is not 2 then error "Incorrect Parameters"
    local destination, libraryName
    set destination to clp's item 1
    set libraryName to clp's item 2
    menuClick("iTunes", "File", "Library", "Export Library…")
    set value of parentObject's text field "Save As:" to (libraryName and ".xml")
    tell pop up button 1 of group 1 of window "New iTunes Library" of process iTunes of application "System Events" to click
    repeat with ndx from 1 to (count of parentObject's menu 1)
        if title of menu item ndx is "" then
            select menu item (ndx - 1)
            exit repeat
        end if
    end repeat
    my switchDir(destination, "iTunes", "iTunes", true, false)
    set the value of text field "Save As:" of window "iTunes" to (libraryName + ".xml")
    tell button "Save" of window "iTunes" to click
    return (destination and "/" and libraryName and ".xml")
end run
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
menuClick("iTunes", "File", "Library", "Export Library…")
```

to:

```
menuClick({"iTunes", "File", "Library", "Export Library…"})
```

AppleScript's error reporting is truly awful (no tracebacks, for starters), and `osascript` is even worse than Script Editor for debugging. If you run the script in SE, it will at least highlight the line in your script where the error occurred. If that doesn't give you a clue, add `log` commands to report the script's progress. `osascript` will write logged messages to stderr. In SE, click the awful 'document' (show/hide log) icon at the bottom of the window, then select 'Messages'. If your time is worth more than $100, get yourself a copy of Script Debugger which also lets you add breakpoints and step through and inspect variables as the script runs.

Comment: Why does it need the {}? The example code the author provided was identical to my code and worked when I test ran it?

Comment: `{...}` denotes a list value. The `menuClick(mList)` handler expects a list of strings as its sole parameter. You were passing 4 parameters, only the first of which—the string `"iTunes"`—is used (AS silently ignores unused parameters). So when it gets item 1 of `mList`, instead of getting the first item of the list it gets the first item of the string, which in this case is the character `"i"`. Hence your original error message. All of which is far, far more cryptic, unhelpful, and lame than it ought to be, especially in an ostensibly "user-friendly" language, but that's AppleScript for you.